# Using filesystem in node.js with async / await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

I would like to use async/await with some filesystem operations. Normally async/await works fine because I use `babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions`.

But with this code I run into the if case where `names` is undefined:

```
import fs from 'fs';

async function myF() {
  let names;
  try {
    names = await fs.readdir('path/to/dir');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('e', e);
  }
  if (names === undefined) {
    console.log('undefined');
  } else {
    console.log('First Name', names[0]);
  }
}

myF();
```

When I rebuild the code into the callback hell version everything is OK and I get the filenames.
Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 244):

## Native support for async/await fs functions since Node 11

Since Node.js 11.0.0 (stable), and 10.0.0 (experimental), you can access file system methods already [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)'d. Thanks to promises you can simply use `try catch` to handle exceptions instead of checking if the callback's returned value contains an error.

The API is very clean and elegant! Simply import file system methods from `fs/promises` instead of importing them directly from `fs`:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises'

async function listDir() {
  try {
    return await fs.readdir('path/to/dir')
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error occurred while reading directory:', err)
  }
}

listDir()
```

Comment: This API is stable as of version 11.x per the [File System documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/fs.html) on the Node.js site

Comment: @DanStarns if you don't `return await` your promise, the catch block is of no use...I thinj it is sometimes a good practice to await before returning

Comment: Documentation for these alternative methods: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: i like doing `import { promises as fs } from 'fs';`

Comment: Suggestion: `import fs from 'fs/promises`;` and then `await fs.readdir(...)`

Answer (score 179):

Starting with node 8.0.0, you can use this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

async function myF() {
  let names;
  try {
    names = await readdir('path/to/dir');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (names === undefined) {
    console.log('undefined');
  } else {
    console.log('First Name', names[0]);
  }
}

myF();
```

See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: In node v8.9.4, got a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` error message. does node8 supports `import` token by default?

Comment: @makerj he's using the new [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax. It currently requires some transpiling. Would be ok to also use `const fs = require('fs')` or `const { promisify } = require('util')`

Comment: Noob question, but what's the `{err, names} = function` syntax called?

Comment: @Qasim it is called destructuring assignment.

Comment: @jaredkwright The destructuring call results in `Unexpected token =` using Node 10.1.0.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler That may be true. I haven't looked to see if that is actually a correct use of destructuring. In the case of async await I think you would just do `names = await readdir('path/to/dir');` and if there is an `err` handle it in the `catch` block. Either way, the name of the syntax is destructuring assignment which was just in response to Qasim's question.

Comment: This is so ugly, why do the only answers to this question throw errors on every version of node? Is it that hard to add an extra line to destructure longform?

Comment: Why is it needed to declare the variable outside the try block, and not inside?

Answer (score 109):

#### Node.js 8.0.0

### Native async / await

#### Promisify

From this version, you can use native Node.js function from **util** library.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile)
const writeFileAsync = promisify(fs.writeFile)

const run = async () => {
  const res = await readFileAsync('./data.json')
  console.log(res)
}

run()
```

---

#### Promise Wrapping

```
const fs = require('fs')

const readFile = (path, opts = 'utf8') =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, opts, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(data)
    })
  })

const writeFile = (path, data, opts = 'utf8') =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(path, data, opts, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve()
    })
  })

module.exports = {
  readFile,
  writeFile
}

...


// in some file, with imported functions above
// in async block
const run = async () => {
  const res = await readFile('./data.json')
  console.log(res)
}

run()
```

#### Advice

*Always use `try..catch` for await blocks, if you don't want to rethrow exception upper.*

Comment: This is strange. I am getting SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function... crying in rage.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. look at comments, `await` must be always in `async` block :)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. You need to call that `const res = await readFile('data.json')
console.log(res)` in some async function

Comment: promise wrapping `fs.promises` and using it with `async/await` is so confusing to me

Comment: @PrimitiveNom Promise can be used in traditional way within `then`, `catch` etc. Where are async/await is modern behavior flow.

Answer (score 75):

### As of *v10.0*, you can use [**`fs.Promises`**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

#### Example using [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options)

```
const { promises: fs } = require("fs");

async function myF() {
    let names;
    try {
        names = await fs.readdir("path/to/dir");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e", e);
    }
    if (names === undefined) {
        console.log("undefined");
    } else {
        console.log("First Name", names[0]);
    }
}

myF();
```

#### Example using [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_readfile_options)

```
const { promises: fs } = require("fs");

async function getContent(filePath, encoding = "utf-8") {
    if (!filePath) {
        throw new Error("filePath required");
    }

    return fs.readFile(filePath, { encoding });
}

(async () => {
    const content = await getContent("./package.json");

    console.log(content);
})();
```

Comment: Works great, but important to note the open issue regarding the `ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental` warning: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1178

Comment: @DavidP what version of node are you using? 12 and above works fine

Comment: Yes! Absolutely correct - I neglected to state version I am on: `v10.15.3` - it's possible to suppress the message. However, with the issue still open I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @DavidP I mean it is worth a mention don't get me wrong, but node 12 is in LTS now so it's not a Biggie.

Comment: how exactly do you use this with, say, `readFile`? im new to this whole promises thing, and all i want to do is have a function `getContent` that i can call and await in various parts throughout my script, yet this is proving very confusing

Comment: @PrimitiveNom you could use [fs.promises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) I have added a code snippet to my answer.

Comment: In TypeScript (and modern JavaScript?) you can write `import { promises as fs } from "fs";`.

Comment: @JanAagaard yeah, you can. There are 2 answers below with import.

Answer (score 49):

You might produce the wrong behavior because the File-Api `fs.readdir` does not return a promise. It only takes a callback. If you want to go with the async-await syntax you could 'promisify' the function like this:

```
function readdirAsync(path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readdir(path, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and call it instead:

```
names = await readdirAsync('path/to/dir');
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird response like this... Buffer(18524) [60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 116, 110, 116, 45, 108, 105, 98, 62, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 47, 42, 42, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 42, 32, 67, 111, 112, 121, 114, 105, 103, 104, 116, 32, 63, 32, 50, 48, 50, 48, 32, 68, 101, 115, 105, 103, 110, 32, 65 …]

Comment: Use [`Buffer.toString`](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/node/buffer-to-string) method.

Answer (score 22):

**Node v14.0.0 and above**

you can just do:

```
import { readdir } from "fs/promises";
```

just like you would import from `"fs"`

see this PR for more details: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31553

Comment: This should be the selected answer as of 2022.

Comment: I like how as I scroll down I get to see the history of file system access in Node.js. xD

Answer (score 20):

This is the TypeScript version to the question. It is usable after Node 11.0:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

async function loadMonoCounter() {
    const data = await fs.readFile('monolitic.txt', 'binary');
    return Buffer.from(data);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have this little helping module that exports [promisified](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) versions of `fs` functions

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {promisify} = require("util")

module.exports = {
  readdir: promisify(fs.readdir),
  readFile: promisify(fs.readFile),
  writeFile: promisify(fs.writeFile)
  // etc...
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me:

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

(async () => {
  try {
    const names = await fsp.readdir('path/to/dir');
    console.log(names[0]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error: ', e);
  }
})();
```

This code works in node 7.6 without babel when [harmony flag](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) is enabled: `node --harmony my-script.js`. And starting with node 7.7, [you don't even need this flag](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions)!

The [`fsp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise) library included in the beginning is just a promisified wrapper for `fs` (and [`fs-ext`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext)).

I’m really exited about what you can do in node without babel these days! Native `async`/`await` make writing code such a pleasure!

**UPDATE 2017-06:** fs-promise module was deprecated. Use [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) instead with the same API.

Comment: Downloading a library for this is pure overkill, dependency bloating is something that the community should be strongly against, infact a new npmjs should come into making that only has libs with 0 dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Recommend using an npm package such as https://github.com/davetemplin/async-file, as compared to custom functions.  For example:

```
import * as fs from 'async-file';

await fs.rename('/tmp/hello', '/tmp/world');
await fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append');
await fs.access('/etc/passd', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK);

var stats = await fs.stat('/tmp/hello', '/tmp/world');
```

Other answers are outdated

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code :

```
fs.promises.readdir(path)

// If promise resolved and
// data are fetched
.then(filenames => {
    for (let filename of filenames) {
        console.log(filename)
    }
})

// If promise is rejected
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple and lightweight module https://github.com/nacholibre/nwc-l it supports both async and sync methods.

Note: this module was created by me.