# How do I wait for multiple fs.readFile calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My objective is to read data from two files and compare the data. My input files are result3.json and result4.json.The data in these files are coma separated.

result3.json

```
[
  "temp1.txt",
  "temp2.txt",
]
```

node:

```
function readFromFile(file) {
    var fileNames = [];
    //setTimeout(function() {
        fs.readFile(file,function(err, data){
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            var temp = JSON.parse(data.toString().split(","));
            // console.log(temp.length);
            for (let index = 0; index < temp.length; index++) {
                //console.log(temp[index]);
                fileNames.push(temp[index]);
                //console.log(fileNames[index]);
            }
            Done(); // to block the async call
        });
        //},3000);
    //console.log(fileNames.length);
    return fileNames;
}

var baseListOfFiles = readFromFile('./output/result3.json'); // Assume this is the base file
var currentListOfFiles = readFromFile('./output/result4.json'); // Assume this is the current file

function Done(){
    //console.log('Out baseListOfFiles + ' + baseListOfFiles.length);
    for (let index = 0; index < baseListOfFiles.length; index++) {
        console.log("[baseListOfFiles] " + baseListOfFiles[index]);
    }

    //console.log('Out currentListOfFiles+ ' + currentListOfFiles.length);
    for (let index = 0; index < currentListOfFiles.length; index++) {
        console.log("[currentListOfFiles] " + currentListOfFiles[index]);
    }

}
```

Above is my code. It seems to be async call, so it always return 0 fileNames.
Is there any way to control it?

Comment: There are several ways to wait for multiple async calls to finish. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413749/node-js-promise-all-and-foreach Also, if those files contain JSON, there's no need to use `toString()` or `split()` or any of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's example code using Promises:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readFromFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    });
}

const promises = [
    readFromFile('./output/result3.json'),
    readFromFile('./output/result4.json')
];

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    baseListOfFiles = result[0];
    currentListOfFiles = result[1];
    // do more stuff
});
```

First, an array `promises` is built; each Promise reads the file, then calls `resolve` with the result.
This array is passed to `Promise.all()`, which `then` calls the callback, passing the array of results in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, `readFile` is async. What you're looking for is `readFileSync`: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

With that can can do:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync(file);

//do something with data
```

There are a few ways to 'promisify' `readFile` if you like, the options are discussed here: [Using filesystem in node.js with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I will try this way

Comment: @PraveerKumar use [util.promisify](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) to wrap `fs.readFile()` into a promise then use async and await if you are using >= NodeJS v8.

Comment: The other answer should be the preferred one actually. JS being asynch by nature, forcing the synch is not a good idea. Imagine the file read for both takes 1min, you don't want to wait 1+1= 2 mins, but instead wait 1min only that both have completed in parallel