# Node.js read file using async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am experimenting with async/await code to read file.
Here's my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    //console.log(test);
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log(fileName)
      console.log(data)
    })
    resolve();
  });
}

async function run() {
  await readFile('file1.txt');
  await readFile('file2.txt');
  readFile('file3.txt');
}

run();
```

But the result is still random. It means file3 sometime read before file2. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You put `resolve` *outside* of the asynchronous call, so it gets resolved immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using filesystem in node.js with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that.

Most of them is explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

I'll write simple one:

1) using `util.promisify` to convert callback method to promise:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = (fileName) => util.promisify(fs.readFile)(fileName, 'utf8');

(async () => {
  try {
    const files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'];
    for (const file of files) {
      console.log(
        await readFile(file)
      );
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

2) `*Sync` methods. Since Your code is not dealing with concurrency You can use `*Sync` methods:

```
const fs = require('fs');

try {
  const files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'];
  for (const file of files) {
    console.log(
      fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    );
  }
}
catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

BTW. Here is Your fixed code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (error, data) {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      console.log(fileName)
      console.log(data)

      resolve();
    })
  });
}

async function run() {
  await readFile('file1.txt');
  await readFile('file2.txt');
  await readFile('file3.txt');
}

run();
```

since You're calling readFile and resolve at same async sequence it's being called at same time which is reason of `race condition`.

You've to wait for callback handling and then resolve it (inside callback scope).

Comment: Thank you for showing other methods to achieve my goal... Actually there are some additional code to process the data. Yes, the code works by moving resolve() to inside fs.readFile(). Alternative 2 is easier to understand.

Answer (score 19):

There are a couple options with native node functionality

### A) With the [`fs.promises` API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on import to alias `fs.promises` as just `fs`

```js
const { promises: fs } = require("fs");

(async () => {
    try {
        let file1 = await fs.readFile("file1.txt", "utf-8");
        let file2 = await fs.readFile("file2.txt", "utf-8");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e", e);
    }
})()
```

### B) With [`util.promisify` API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```js
const fsSync = require("fs");
const {promisify} = require("util")

const fs = {
  readdir: promisify(fsSync.readdir),
  readFile: promisify(fsSync.readFile),
  // etc
};

(async () => {
    try {
        let file1 = await fs.readFile("file1.txt", "utf-8");
        let file2 = await fs.readFile("file2.txt", "utf-8");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e", e);
    }
})()
```

#### Further Reading

- [How to read file with async/await properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46867517/1366033)
- [Using filesystem in node.js with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593875/1366033)