# fs.readFile Unit test case - "Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?"

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, fs

I am currently writing unit test case using jest for a method that used fs.readFile .I have been trying to test the logic inside the fs.readFile without no success.So i tried to log  inside the function like below

**My function to test**

```
fileUpload = (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    // Reading the file
    fs.readFile(request.file.path, async (error, file) => {
        console.log('Hey i am inside')
        const entity = await this.model.fileUpload(x, y, z);
    });
};
```

**My test case so far**

```
    it('should perform file upload', async () => {
       ....
       await Promise.resolve(controller.fileUpload(request as Request, response as Response))
       ....
    });
```

**Error Thrown**

---

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
>   async in your test?
>       Attempted to log "Hey i am inside".

---

Why is this error shown,even when i return a resolved promise in the test file.I infer that the tests are completed before control enters fs.readFile. What should i do to wait for the completion of fs.readFile ?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` doesn't return a Promise, and neither (from the snippet) does your code for the `fileUpload` to run an `await` against. You'd need to make `fileUpload` return a Promise which resolves when the entire function is done.

Comment: I am trying not to edit the existing code just for test.Is there any other way i can test ?

Comment: Just in case you want `fs.readFile` to return a promise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034648/node-js-read-file-using-async-await