# Write Event Hub Messages to local file with Azure Function Core Tools

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an Event Hub Triggered TypeScript Azure Function. I am trying to write the events receive to a local file when executing with Azure Function Core Tools. This is just to help with development, and not something I will be doing in production or inside of Azure itself.

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions"
import fs = require('fs');

const eventHubTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, eventHubMessages: any[]): Promise<void> {
    context.log(`Eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);

    eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {
        context.log(`Processed message ${message}`);

        let data = JSON.stringify(message, null, 2);
        fs.writeFile('messages.json', data, { flag: 'a+' }, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            context.log('Data written to file');
        });

    });
};

export default eventHubTrigger;
```

When I run this function with the Azure Function Core Tools, there is no 'messages.json' file in the project root (or anywhere I can find). Please advice on how I can write this JSON data to local disk when executing with Azure Function Core Tools.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `fs.writeFile` is an asynchronous operation but the function doesn't wait for it since the function is made `async` without any `await`.

Here is one way you can fix it by not using `async` and calling [`context.done()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#contextdone-method) instead

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions"
import fs = require('fs');

const eventHubTrigger: AzureFunction = function (context: Context, eventHubMessages: any[]): Promise<void> {
  context.log(`Eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);

  let dataToWrite = "";
  eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {
    context.log(`Processed message ${message}`);

    let data = JSON.stringify(message, null, 2);
    dataToWrite += data;
  });

  fs.writeFile('messages.json', dataToWrite, { flag: 'a+' }, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    context.log('Data written to file');
    context.done();
  });
};

export default eventHubTrigger;
```

Another way would be to `promisify` the `fs` methods as covered in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593875/10417839).