# Protractor - read in spec 2 a CSV file populated in spec 1

Tags: javascript, file, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using Protractor to automate some tests.

In spec 1, I do some actions and collect some information in a CSV file:

```
describe("Spec 1", function () {

  for (let i of some_useful_array) {
    it("does some business", async function () {
      saveData(someData)
    })
  }

  function saveData(someData) {
    fs.appendFile("./file.csv", "\n" + someData, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }

})
```

In spec 2, I would like to use this information:

```
var myFile= fs.readFileSync('./file.csv');

const data = parse(myFile, {
  columns: true,
  skip_empty_lines: true
})

describe("Spec 2", function () {

  for (let i of some_other_useful_array) {
    it("does some other business", function () {
      console.log(data) // logs an empty array ([]) when run in the same execution than spec 1
    })
  }
})
```

It works like a charm when I run spec 1 and spec 2 separately, but it doesn't work when I run them in the same execution. I guess I need to close something, I have tried some things (for example `fs.close()`) but none of these worked.

Any idea?

**EDIT**: I tried something: copy file.csv to file2.csv in spec 1, and use file2.csv in spec 2. It seems to work a bit better. Nasty workaround though, but good enough until I bump into a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[fs.appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) is asynchronous, meaning that javascript doesn't wait until it finishes it's task. Basically spec 2 is ran before csv is fully created. This probably won't be an issue when you run the real spec which will take at least a few seconds. But to be safe, you better go with [fs.appendFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) which does the same but doesn't schedule another task until this one is done

another ways for solving this behavior described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463672/9150146

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem that I face but it's helping me investigating though. Thanks