# How to wait for the callback to be finished with fs.readdir?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback, fs

I'm using fs.readdir callback function to do stuff in a path file but i want to wait for the callback to be finished to continue on with the rest of my code.

```
const get = async(path_files) => {
    fs.readdir(path_files, function(err, files) {
        do stuff that takes time;
    })
};
```

When I call this function, I want the console.log to run after the callback of fs.readdir (which is not the case with this code).

```
const start_get = async() => {
    await get(path_files);
    console.log("the stuff was done");

}
```

I've seen similars answers on the website but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promise-example

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await