# Reading a JSON file in node immediately after the JSON file is written returns ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, json

so I was making a program that scrapes a website and stores the data in json format with fs.writeFile and another program that read from the stored json using fs.readFile, but the fs.readFile returns "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open...."

```
fs.readFile("./json/productVariables.json","utf-8",(err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("could not read the JSON file " + err);
        } else {
          const productVariable = JSON.parse(data);
}});
```

I've even wrapped it with fs.access to check if the file exists, but still returns the same error

```
fs.access("productVariables.json", fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("JSON file doesn't exist " + err);
  }
  fs.readFile(
    "./json/productVariables.json",
    "utf-8",
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("could not read the JSON file " + err);
      } else {
        const productVariable = JSON.parse(data);
      }
    }
  )
})
```

I've checked the file path and it's all correct, and I can literally see it in the directory

when I use require to parse the JSON file it works, but I want to use fs to check is the file is present and to parse from the file if it exists. Why is it returning no such file or directory error when the file is actually there

**Edit**

I wrote the JSON file with fsPromises like this

```
await fsPromises.writeFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "json", "productVarables.json"),
      JSON.stringify(variables),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error while writing the JSON" + err);
        } else {
          console.log("successfuly written the JSON file");
        }
      }
    );
```

and when I try to read it using fsPromises like this

```
await fsPromises.readFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "json", "productVarables.json"),
      "utf-8",
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    );
```

I get the following error

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\desktop\Project\Node\Scraper\json\productVariables.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\desktop\\Project\\Node\\Scraper\\json\\productVariables.json'
}
```

Comment: try using fs promises to make sure the write is finished before reading. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753481/11616708

Comment: You have two different paths. You are checking `"./productVariables.json"` but then trying to read `"./json/productVariables.json"`